# How to have bootstrap tab links link to another partial file in ruby on rails to display content?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bootstrap-4, hyperlink, tabs

I'm currently trying to incorporate Bootstrap tabs into my app. When I click on each tab, I want the content to also be different. However, I'm not sure how to do so with the rails language. Currently, I'm trying to render my partial like this:

<

```
ul class="nav nav-tabs justify-content-center">
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Active</a>
    
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
    <%= render :partial => "teams_list", locals: {teams: @teams} %>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I used bootstrap for getting nav-tabs. It's a very easy implementation. I showed some static data here. You can easily use ruby code here. And I used js for selecting the first tab initially. You can easily check it by removing it from the code snippet.

```js
$(function () {
  $('#myTab li:first-child a').tab('show') 
})
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container tab-bar">
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" id="tab1-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#tab1" role="tab" aria-controls="tab1" aria-selected="false">By
        Tab1</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" id="tab2-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#tab2" role="tab" aria-controls="tab2" aria-selected="true">Tab2</a>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane" id="tab1" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="tab1-tab">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="row p-2">
                  <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 p-2">Tab1--Child1</div>
                  <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 p-2">Tab1--Child2</div>
                  <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 p-2">Tab1--Child3</div>
            </div>
          </div>
    </div>

    <div class="tab-pane" id="tab2" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="tab2-tab">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row p-2">
              <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 p-2">Tab2--Child1</div>
              <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 p-2">Tab2--Child2</div>
              <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 p-2">Tab2--Child3</div>
              <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 p-2">Tab2--Child4</div>
              <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 p-2">Tab2--Child5</div>
              <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 p-2">Tab2--Child6</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I am mentioning the ruby code inside a tab using partial.

```
<div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane" id="tab1" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="tab1-tab">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="row p-2">
                 <% @teams.each do |team| %>
                  <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 p-2">
                      <%= render partial: 'team', locals:{team:team} %>
                  </div>
                 <% end %>
            </div>
          </div>
    </div>
</div>
```